# Variable suddenly becoming null?

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

Ok, I know how ridiculous or lame it sounds, so risking my reputation here, I'm asking, how is this possible:

```
player = new MediaPlayerCompat();
player.setWakeMode(XenoAmpService.this, PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
player.reset();
player.setOnPreparedListener(null);

try {
    player.setDataSource(spath);
    player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC); // NullPointerException?!?!?!
```

Note that AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC is static (pasted from Android source):

```
public static final int STREAM_MUSIC = AudioSystem.STREAM_MUSIC;
```

How could this create NPE at this line with setDataSource not causing it?

Note: I can't debug it because it's not on my machine. It's a crashlytics raport. Happens for single user, doesn't happen for 1000s others.

Note 2: spath isn't null either, it's handled earlier in the code. player.setAudioStreamType checks for possible nulls too, but the code doesn't reach it anyway...

Note 3: Stack trace (don't think it will help, though)...

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void pl.qus.xenoamp.helper.MediaPlayerCompat.setAudioStreamType(int)' on a null object reference
       at pl.qus.xenoamp.xenoservice.XenoAmpService$AggregateMediaPlayer.prepare(XenoAmpService.java:2433)
       at pl.qus.xenoamp.xenoservice.XenoAmpService$AggregateMediaPlayer.zastąpDrugi(XenoAmpService.java:2577)
       at pl.qus.xenoamp.xenoservice.XenoAmpService.zmieńDrugiWrapper(XenoAmpService.java:2238)
       at pl.qus.xenoamp.xenoservice.XenoAmpService$AggregateMediaPlayer$1$2$1.execute(XenoAmpService.java:2520)
       at pl.qus.threading.StoppableRunnable.run(StoppableRunnable.java:48)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: Why don't you simply debug to see what's null?

Comment: I can't debug it because it's not on my machine. It's a crashlytics raport. Happens for single user, doesn't happen for 1000s others.

Comment: Show us the stacktrace. Crashlytics should support one. Maybe an internal bug in the player?

Comment: Is `player` shared between multiple threads? Another thread could have set it to null after the call to setDataSource but before the call to setAudioStreamType.

Comment: That's the first thing that came to my mind (cause it is), BUT there's no place where I null the player!

Comment: do you have access to the code of `XenoAmpService.java`? NPE occurred at `line#2433` inside the `prepare()` method.

Comment: Yes, you have the offending code up there.

Comment: could you, please, add more of the stacktrace?? I really belive the nullpointer is somewhere within the MediaPlayerCompat in a class named just the same (the name `AggregateMediaPlayer` smells like so).  By the way, is your variable declared of this type `pl.qus.xenoamp.helper.MediaPlayerCompat`?

Comment: That's whole stacktrace of offending thread I got from crashlytics. MediaPlayerCompat is heavily guarded with !=null, the npe is clearly in XenoAmpService$AggregateMediaPlayer code shown above.

Comment: Note also that if it was due to player being nulled from another process it would cause npe in may different, random places. And I have 20-something exceptions always in the same line.